# Why do python scripts run through CGI/WSGI on unix-like systems fail if the file has CRLF line endings?

Tags: python, linux, cgi, webserver, wsgi

In the past, there have been several instances where I have tried to run a Python script under CGI or WSGI, only to get the following ambiguous error in my webserver's log:

```
[error] [client <client>] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/path/to/web/root/test.py' failed
```

This happens even with a very simple script, i.e:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

print "Hello, World!"
```

In the past, I have managed to solve the issue by making sure the file used unix line endings, but out of curiosity, I have the following questions:

1. **To my knowledge, the above error means that the python executable cannot be found; am I correct?**
2. **In the case that the python executable cannot be found, why? Does the CRLF endings break the shebang line?**
3. **Is there a workaround for this other than converting the format? Is it possible to configure CGI/WSGI in such a way to handle this automatically?**

I have verified this specific example with Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 11.04, running Python 2.6 under CGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the case that the python executable cannot be found, why? Does the CRLF endings break the shebang line?

Yup, that's it.

> Is there a workaround for this other than converting the format? Is it possible to configure CGI/WSGI in such a way to handle this automatically?

Something that doesn't make you want to puke? I don't think so.

Answer (score -2):

Python will be able to handle the CRLF line endings, but Linux/Unix is expecting only LF as the line ending, so an incredible ugly workaround could be (having the ^M as part of the filename):

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python^M
```

Note that you have to escape the ^M from the command line, so in bash it would be ^V^M.